How to overcome not minting problem when calling function from smart contract
I am trying to call a function from my contract with ethers.js v6 but facing some problems.
This is my code.
const gasLimit = await contract.writeResult.estimateGas(args);
const { gasPrice } = await provider.getFeeData();

const result = await contract.writeResult(args, { gasLimit, gasPrice });
console.log(result.hash);
await result.wait();

Here I can see result.hash but result.wait() took infinitive.
What is the problem and how to overcome this situation?

can you log the gasprice. if it logs a resonable number, multiply by 1000 to increase the gas price manually and try it.
result waits because transaction does not get mined.

gasPrice is 1000000000n and when I multiply it by 1000 it is still the same, not getting mined
